# Send a JSONArray POST request with android volley library

Tags: java, android, json, http-post, android-volley

I would like to send and receive a Json Array with volley. 
Now I can receive an array and it's ok but I don't know how to send a request (For example: with post method).

```
JsonArrayRequest arrayReq = new JsonArrayRequest(URL,
            new Listener<JSONArray>() {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 List<Map<String,String>> listMap =  new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
        Map<String,String> map  = new HashMap<String,String>();
        try {

            map.put("email", customer.getEmail());
            map.put("password",customer.getPassword());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        listMap.add(map);

        String url = PersonalConstants.BASE_URL+"/url";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, url, String.valueOf(new JSONArray(listMap)),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        Log.d(App.TAG, jsonObject.toString());
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener (){

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Log.d(App.TAG,volleyError.toString());
            }
        }
        );
        App.getInstance().getmRequestQueue().add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
// Define the web service URL
final String URL = "http://www.someurl.com";

// POST params to be sent to the server
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("name", "raha tamjid");

// Define the POST request
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
   new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
           try {
               VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
       }
   });

// Add the request object to the queue to be executed
ApplicationController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

How the POST request differs is that it takes a `JSONObject` as parameter.

**EDIT 1:**

If you have `Volley` installed as a library project in your IDE, then just define a new constructor

```
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest,
    Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener, errorListener);
}
```

inside the class `JsonArrayRequest` which is present in the `Volley` library code. Now you can use this to create `JsonArrayRequest` objects and add them to the `RequestQueue`.

**EDIT 2:**

**1.** Get the Volley library project from [here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley). Download the project and set it up in your IDE.

**2.** Make the modification to the `JsonRequest` class (found in `com.android.volley.toolbox` namespace) as discussed in **EDIT 1**.

**3.** Delete the `volley.jar` from the `libs` folder of your **APPLICATION PROJECT**.

**4.** Now go to Project Properties -> Android -> Library and click on **Add**. From here select the `Volley` project. Clean & Rebuild.

**5.** Now in your **APPLICATION PROJECT** you can make a POST `JsonArrayRequest` just like how we make a POST `JsonObjectRequest` and get a `JSONArray` in the `Response`.

Comment: thank you . but i want to get Json Array in response not Json Object .

Comment: no . i have the volley 's .jar file . how to do that can you show me ?thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and extend JsonArrayRequest then override

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("name", "value");
    return params;
}

and add a new constructor and in it call

super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);

or use this class

public class PostJsonArrayRequest extends JsonRequest<JSONArray> {

    /**
     * Creates a new request.
     * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
     * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
     * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
     */
    public PostJsonArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name", "value");
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString =
                    new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new java class named JsonArrayPostRequest now you can use it like the previous request, just replace JSONArrayRequest with JsonArrayPostRequest and pass the correct parameters

```
public  class JsonArrayPostRequest extends Request<JSONArray>{  
    private Map<String,String> mParam;  
    private Listener<JSONArray>  mListener;  


    public JsonArrayPostRequest(String url,Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener,Map param) {  
        super(Request.Method.POST, url, errorListener);  
        mListener=listener;  
        mParam=param;   
    }  
    @Override  
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {  
        return mParam;  
    }  

       @Override  
        protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {  
            try {  
                String jsonString =  
                    new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));  
                return Response.success(new JSONArray(jsonString),  
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));  
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));  
            } catch (JSONException je) {  
                return Response.error(new ParseError(je));  
            }  
        }  

    @Override  
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONArray response) {  
        mListener.onResponse(response);  

    }  

}
```

USE:

```
JsonArrayPostRequest request = new JsonArrayPostRequest(URL,new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(),             
                new Response.ErrorListener() ,params);
```