# get the data from edittext of recyclerview and post it in server using json android

Tags: android

I have an EditText in RecyclerView in which i am able to increase or decrease the quantity. Now I want to get the quantity of EditText and post it in JSON Array and send to server

Comment: Check out [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [volly](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: I am using volley to display the list and in each row of recyclerview there is edittext and problem is to get the value from edittext and post it on server

Comment: Then you want to look up how to POST. I would put it into a hashmap -- i.e "key" : editText.getText().toString() and then send it. Here's a great thread that has several answers and different implementations [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28656935/4329778)